# How to have a local dns server with no conflict with internet addresses?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I need a local dns server on an ubuntu server to resolve name of local servers. I used dnsmasq, but the problem is that it tries to resolve all addresses (for example http://serverfault.com) and resolve it with a wrong ip address.

How should I make dnsmasq not to resolve names that it has no ip for them, so clients may use alternate dns server? Or if I have to use another dns server, what to use?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define [`zones`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

> --auth-zone=[,[/][,[/].....]]
>    Define a DNS zone for which dnsmasq acts as authoritative server. Locally defined DNS records which are in the domain will be served. If subnet(s) are given, A and AAAA records must be in one of the specified subnets.

Also note that:

> Dnsmasq is a DNS query forwarder: it it not capable of recursively answering arbitrary queries starting from the root servers but forwards such queries to a fully recursive upstream DNS server which is typically provided by an ISP. By default, dnsmasq reads /etc/resolv.conf to discover the IP addresses of the upstream nameservers it should use, since the information is typically stored there. Unless --no-poll is used, dnsmasq checks the modification time of /etc/resolv.conf (or equivalent if --resolv-file is used) and re-reads it if it changes.